# MySQL find all rows where rows with number of rows for possible values of column is less than n

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with columns `foo_name` and `foo_type`

`foo_type` can have values of `A`, `B` or `C`

I want to find all `foo_name` where the table does not have `foo_name` with all possible values of `foo_type`. In other words,

```
DISTINCT(foo_name) WHERE COUNT(rows grouped by foo_name) for all foo_name is less than 3
```

Sample Data

```
Foo, A
Foo, B
Foo, C
Bar, B
Bar, C
Baz, A
Qux, A
Qux, B
Qux, C
```

My query should return *Bar* and *Baz* because those `foo_name` don't have rows for all possible values of `foo_type`.

Appreciate pointers to working SQL that does the above.

Additionally, I want to be able to extend the above from count() to find all `foo_name` where `foo_type` of some value (or values) not found. In the above sample data, I would want to be able to search for all `foo_name` where row matching `foo_name` and for `foo_type = A` not found (Answer: *Bar*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a simple aggregate. You want a row per foo_name in your results, so you GROUP BY foo_name. Then limit your results in HAVING:

```
select foo_name
from my_table
group by foo_name
having count(distinct foo_type) < 3;
```

You can easily change your HAVING clause in order to know what types where found for a foo_name, e.g.:

```
select foo_name
from my_table
group by foo_name
having max(case when foo_type = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 -- A not found
   and max(case when foo_type = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) = 1 -- B found
   and max(case when foo_type = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) = 1 -- C found
```

EDIT: Here is the same with another HAVING clause which may be easier to understand:

```
select foo_name
from my_table
group by foo_name
having group_concat(distinct foo_type order by foo_type) = 'B,C';
```

Answer (score 2):

There are probably several ways to do this, but I would do it with a subquery. So something like this ...

```
SELECT foo_name 
FROM ( SELECT foo_name, COUNT(DISTINCT(foo_type)) AS foo_type_count 
       FROM foo_table
       GROUP BY foo_name ) as sq
WHERE foo_type_count != 3
```

The subquery (inside the parentheses) returns all of the foo_name values and a count of how many different foo_types are set for each of the those values. Then you select some of the foo_name values depending on some other criteria - in the case I provided, you could pull out all of the foo_names that do not have all of the three foo_types associated with them.

If you want to tweak this, you can then add WHERE clauses inside the subquery, so you could do `WHERE foo_type != A` inside the subquery and change the WHERE clause outside the subquery to match `WHERE foo_type_count = 2` - this would return all foo_names which have foo_types B and C, whether or not that have A. So for your sample data set, it should return Foo, Bar, and Qux, but not Baz.

Comment: Though not wrong, it would be easier (and maybe performance wise better, depending on how much data OP has) to use a `HAVING` clause. For your tweaking, here's a hint: `SUM(<boolean expression>)`

Answer (score 0):

If you'd prefer not to have to manually type in the number `3`, but rather to have the database do the work for you, you could do something like this:

```
-- Note: you can change foo_temp_name to whatever you want (even foo_name).
-- I just changed it here so it would stand out. The same goes for temp_table.
-- Note: Change mytable to whatever your table's name is.
SELECT foo_temp_name FROM (
  SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT(foo_type)) < (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(foo_type)) FROM mytable)
        THEN foo_name
    END
  AS foo_temp_name
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY foo_name
) temp_table
WHERE foo_temp_name IS NOT NULL
```